# Perform omit on the original object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am very new to underscore js, I am trying to omit a certain property on an Object. What I did was

```
myObj = _.omit(myObj,name)
console.log(myObj);
```

Still the myObj seems to have the property `name`. Although if I do this it seemes to work

```
newMyObj= _.omit(myObj,name) 
console.log (newMyObj)
```

it seemed to work fine. What am I doing wrong, can someone help? Ok, so `myObj` looks like this

```
Angola: "4.134137685",Brunei: "2.532726835",Countries: "2004",Croatia: "1.717672961", keys: Array[11]
```

I am trying to omit "keys" which again is an array of objects

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the code / or a very similar version of it? As you've written it there are no errors.

Comment: Do you want to put quotation marks around the "name"? Or, you could always just do `delete myObj.name;` (or `delete myObj[name]` if `name` contains the name of the property to delete).

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni, I have added how the object looks like, is this enough or do you need a fiddle?

Comment: Are you sure `name === 'keys'`? It looks like it should work. Care to provide a more complete scenario?

Comment: What you're doing should work (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9nAfB/). Are you really doing `o = _.omit(o, name)` rather than just `_.omit(o, name)`? `_.omit` won't modify the object in-place.

Comment: Dear @Sai, were any of these answers helpful to you?

Comment: @torazaburo, Definitely yes, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are these things called "debuggers". If you don't know what they are, then stop everything you're doing and learn about them now. Search Google for "Chrome devtools", for instance. Stop your code (put a breakpoint) at the point before the call to `_.omit`. In the console, type in `myObj` to see exactly what it contains, then also `name`. Or, you could use the 'Scope Variables" section of devtools to check the value of these variables. Now, make a single step (F10). See if or how the variables have changed, or type `myObj` again into the console to check its value.

In your particular case, you report that the deletion of the property occurs properly when you do

```
newMyObj= _.omit(myObj,name)
```

but not with

```
myObj= _.omit(myObj,name)
```

In and of itself, that behavior is completely unexplainable. So there's something else going on that you're not telling us about. My guess is that you are doing something like this:

```
myObj = { keys: [] };
name = "keys";
delete_property();
console.log(myObj.keys); // []

function delete_property(myObj) {
    myObj = _.omit (myObj, name);
}
```

However, this does not do what you might think. The assignment to `myObj` within the function does nothing; it just reassigns the value of the function argument. It has no effect on the myObj outside the function.

To be sure, we'd need to see more of your actual code, but this is just a regular old debugging problem of the sort you will encounter thousands of times in your programming career, so you're better off learning to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted this question to mean you simply want to remove a property from an object using omit().  Note that omit() returns a copy of the object sans the specified property to remove.  The method does not alter the object in place.

Given this premise, the code below, which matches what you have, works just fine:

```
var copy,
    obj = {
        Angola: "4.134137685",
        Brunei: "2.532726835",
        Countries: "2004",
        Croatia: "1.717672961", 
        keys: Array[11]
    },
    check = function (o) {
        _.each(o, function (value, key) {
            console.log("key: " + key + " value: " + value);
        });
    };


copy = _.omit(obj, "keys");
check(copy);

obj = _.omit(obj, "keys");
check(obj);
```

You will get the same result whether you are using a new variable or the existing one.